# Event onResize not working on tag img

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
        function onLoad(img) {
            alert(img.width);
            alert(img.height);
        }   

        function clickc() {
            var a = document.getElementById("testdiv1");
            a.style.display = "inline";
        }

        function onResize(img) {
            alert(img.width);
            alert(img.height);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="testdiv1" style="display: none;">
        <img id="testImg" src="C:\workspaces\hudsonspace28\g6-formcenter-test\bin\com\senior\formcenter\test\file\resources\Tulipas.jpg" onload="onLoad(this);" onresize="onResize(this);"/>
    </div>
    <button onclick="clickc()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

In IE10, when the page is loaded, the `onLoad` is called. Printed 0 on the screen. 
When I click the button the `clickc` is called, then`onResize` is called and prints the image size.

Okay, but if I add the events `onLoad` and `onResize` dynamically to `IMG`, only `onLoad` will be called.

Exemple:

```
<div id="testdiv1" style="display: none;">
    <img id="testImg" src="C:\workspaces\hudsonspace28\g6-formcenter-test\bin\com\senior\formcenter\test\file\resources\Tulipas.jpg"/>
</div>
<button onclick="clickc()"/>
<script>
    document.getElementById("testImg").addEventListener("load", onLoad, false);
    document.getElementById("testImg").addEventListener("resize", onResize, false);
</script>
```

My objective is get the size of the image when possible, because in this situation, Chrome/Firefox/IE11 returns the size of the image in `onLoad`, but in the IE9/IE10 returns the size 0.

Comment: An image doesn't have a `resize` event, why would it ?

Comment: In Chrome or Firefox the event `resize` is never called. But in IE9 or IE10 is called when I set the style of parent `div` to `display: inline`.